# What is the max size of an attachment the we can move to 3rd party server using SOAP web service (Not REST) from Salesforce?

Tags: apex, webservices

I need to upload the attachments of the records belongs to an object in Salesforce to 3rd party server. 
I checked for solutions on this and found every one used REST API to achieve this as it is the lightest service to use and the size of the attachment they were able to upload is more than 5 MB. We need to know what is the file size we can achieve using SOAP to find the best approach.

Salesforce increased the attachment size limit from 5 MB to 25 MB. we want to know the max size achievable using 2 types of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move total request of 3 MB in size. And can retrieve 3 MB (3 million characters) using REST API. It is exceptional that you have crossed the governor limit of Salesforce.

According to winter'15 version 32, Maximum size of webservice callout request or response can be 3 MB.

You can upload document upto 25 MB by Salesforce UI only.

If using SOAP API outside salesforce then you can create:
Attachment to a maximum size of 25 MB. A file attached to a Solution can be 1.5 MB.

Comment: Hi Regal, Can you please provide any link or reference where you get this information about solution about 1.5 MB and Can you elaborate this?

Comment: I referred Winter'15 version 32 release notes for this information and I didn't find it. Can you please provide more information and references?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm See "usage" section. @KiVee